# What is the right way to make a loop in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created other pages also but I am showing you one. I have made another function specifically for looping but it's not giving me the result. Its giving me the error. Where to put `find_items` function? Or Is there any other problem?

Here is the error:

```
yield from find_items(response, names1, finder1)
NameError: name 'find_items' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
    # save and call request to another page
    dct = [(self.about_page, self.parse_about)]
    for page, callback in dct:
        yield response.follow(page, callback, meta={'items': items})

def find_items(response, names1, finder1):
    items = response.meta['items']
    for name, find in zip(names1.values(), names1.values()):
        items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
        yield items


def parse_about(self, response):
    # do your stuff on second page
    # items = response.meta['items']
    names1 = {'name1': 'Headings',
          'name2': 'Paragraphs',
          'name3': '3 Projects',
          'name4': 'About Dmoz',
          'name5': 'Languages',
          'name6': 'You can make a differnce', 
          'name7': 'Further Information'
          }

    finder1 = {'find1': 'h2::text , #mainContent h1::text',
           'find2': 'p::text',
               'find3': 'li~ li+ li b a::text , li:nth-child(1) b a::text',
               'find4': '.nav ul a::text , li:nth-child(2) b a::text',
               'find5': '.nav~ .nav a::text',
           'find6': 'dd::text , #about-contribute::text',
           'find7': 'li::text , #about-more-info a::text'
          }

    yield from find_items(response, names1, finder1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case `find_items` should be *outside* your class.

If you want to use it inside class, check indents and add `self` to parameters:

```
def find_items(self, response, names1, finder1):
    items = response.meta['items']
    for name, find in zip(names1.values(), names1.values()):
        items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
        yield items
```

And in `parse_about` don't forget also to add `self.`:

```
yield from self.find_items(response, names1, finder1)
```

Besides this, check your Python version. Usage `yield from` appeared only on 3.x version. For 2.x version you should use:

```
for item in self.find_items(response, names1, finder1):
    yield item
```